# how to display text as input is being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the text field as it is being typed on the input field

Here what I have done so far

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    };
  }

  changeText(evt){
    let txt = this.state.text ;
    txt = evt.target.value
    this.setState({
       text: txt
    })
}

   render() {
     return(
       <div>
          <input name="option" type="text" onPress={(evt) => changeText(evt)}/>
          <div>{this.state.text}</div>
       </div>
     )  
  }
```

There is no result showing up as I update the input element

Comment: Can you please change onPress to onChange.?

Comment: also, this.changeText(evt) and bind this in your constructor or use arrow functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this way.
it's easy to read and reusable.

the state will be created on the name of the form element.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      option: ""
    };
  }

  changeText = evt =>{
      this.setState({[evt.target.name]:evt.target.value})
  }

   render() {
    return(
      <div>
          <input name="option" type="text" value={this.state.option} onChange={this.changeText} />
          <div>{this.state.option}</div>
      </div>

    )  
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of input to the state `<input name="option" type="text" value={this.state.text} onPress={(evt) => changeText(evt)}/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChangeText` inside your input field and then use the state value wherever you want to show it, like:

```
onChangeText{(value)=>this.setState({text: value })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntkqxw

you need to change `onPress to onChange` & `changeText(evt) to this.changeText(evt)`